# Java Loop is not doing what It should be doing

Tags: java, loops, methods

Had a problem with the recursive conflictCheck() method. That seems fine now. I have print lines for testing, that look good. Now, when something is a conflict (returns true), my playChess() method is supposed to fix the conflict by adjusting the node's second variable, and so on.

My result is literally:

1,1

2,3

3,1

4,3

5,1
...

Even though the output says "oh we have a conflict" it doesn't act on it once it reaches x,3

```
    public static boolean conflictCheck(QueenNode a, QueenNode b) {
    //checks for conflicts between head and all other nodes in the stack
    if (b == null) {
        System.out.println("Attempting Conflict Check: Nothing to Compare to");
        return false;
    }

    if (a.getRow()!=b.getRow() && a.getColumn()!=b.getColumn() && !diagonal(a,b)){
        System.out.println("Comparing " + a.getRow() + " ," + a.getColumn() +
                                    " And " + b.getRow() + " , " + b.getColumn());
        conflictCheck(a,b.getNext());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("There is a conflict with " +a.getRow() + "," + a.getColumn()
                            + " And " + b.getRow() + "," + b.getColumn());
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}


    public static void playChess() {
    System.out.println("Playing chess");
    //Either there is a conflict between head and another node, the stack isn't full, or we have solution
    if (conflictCheck(head, head.getNext())) {
        if (head.getColumn() == 8) {
            queens.pop();
        }
        else if (!queens.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Adjusting head");
            head.setColumn(head.getColumn()+1);
            System.out.println("Head is now " + head.getRow() + ", " + head.getColumn());
            playChess();

        }
    }

    else if (queens.size() < 8) {
        System.out.println("Stack isn't full yet");
        queens.push(queens.size()+1,1);
        queens.viewPieces();
        playChess();
        }
    else {
        success= true;
        System.out.println("Success");
        queens.viewPieces();
        return;
    }
}
```

The entire output:

```
The stack
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
Attempting Conflict Check: Nothing to Compare to
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
2, 1
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
There is a conflict with 2,1 And 1,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 2, 2
Playing chess
problem
There is a conflict with 2,2 And 1,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 2, 3
Playing chess
Comparing 2 ,3 And 1 , 1
Attempting Conflict Check: Nothing to Compare to
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
Comparing 3 ,1 And 2 , 3
There is a conflict with 3,1 And 1,1
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
4, 1
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
There is a conflict with 4,1 And 3,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 4, 2
Playing chess
problem
There is a conflict with 4,2 And 3,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 4, 3
Playing chess
Comparing 4 ,3 And 3 , 1
There is a conflict with 4,3 And 2,3
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
5, 1
4, 3
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
Comparing 5 ,1 And 4 , 3
There is a conflict with 5,1 And 3,1
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
6, 1
5, 1
4, 3
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
There is a conflict with 6,1 And 5,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 6, 2
Playing chess
problem
There is a conflict with 6,2 And 5,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 6, 3
Playing chess
Comparing 6 ,3 And 5 , 1
There is a conflict with 6,3 And 4,3
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
7, 1
6, 3
5, 1
4, 3
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
Comparing 7 ,1 And 6 , 3
There is a conflict with 7,1 And 5,1
Stack isn't full yet
The stack
8, 1
7, 1
6, 3
5, 1
4, 3
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
Playing chess
There is a conflict with 8,1 And 7,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 8, 2
Playing chess
problem
There is a conflict with 8,2 And 7,1
Adjusting head
Head is now 8, 3
Playing chess
Comparing 8 ,3 And 7 , 1
There is a conflict with 8,3 And 6,3
Success
The stack
8, 3
7, 1
6, 3
5, 1
4, 3
3, 1
2, 3
1, 1
End of stack
```

Comment: Please show your complete output.

Comment: adding now, i'll edit my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, there's a small hint:

The reason that you do not act on a conflict that you detect is most likely because you ignore the return value of `conflictCheck(a,b.getNext());` that you call recursively from `boolean conflictCheck(QueenNode a, QueenNode b)`.

The problem of eight queens is explored in depth in [this excellent work by E.W.Dijkstra](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/agbkb/lehre/programmiersprachen/artikel/EWD-notes-structured.pdf) on page 72. It's coded in ALGOL-60 (which become obsolete even before my time), but the ideas are language-agnostic.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be ignoring the value though

Comment: @JackieAldama The return value is ignored because you call `conflictCheck` on the `getNext()`, but when the boolean comes back to you, your code neither returns it nor assigns it to a local variable for further analysis.

Comment: Breaking down that method though, every time a comparison happens, it should print out "Comparing x and y" but it only prints that on the first comparison. I know it's comparing others in the stack though, because I ccan have it print "Conflict with x and z", so it's doing the comparison. That is something beyond the boolean returning, isn't it??

Comment: @JackieAldama Oh, most definitely there's stuff beyond ignoring a return of a boolean. You do need to bring it in order before you can further debug your program, though. I suggest splitting it in two parts: one that compares two single nodes, ignoring `getNext`, and one that compares individual nodes from the list without recursion, assuming that individual node-to-node comparator works fine. This will simplify your logic and your debug output immensely.